# Объясните что делает данный код?

Tags: javascript

Изучаю создание подсчета количества слов в тексте и не совсем понимаю принцип работы следующего кода. Пожалуйста, объясните.
Не понимаю для чего используется здесь двойной массив:

```
if (arr[arr[i]]) {
arr[arr[i]] += 1;
arr.splice(i, 1);
} else {
arr[arr[i]] = 1;
```

Не понимаю, принцип работы метода sort именно здесь:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
return arr[b] - arr[a];
});
```

И не понимаю совсем для чего используется вот этот вот кусок, понимаю только, что мы создаём JSON, но для чего он нужен и что за переменные в нём используются - не понимаю:

```
var stringResult = JSON.stringify(arr, function(k, v) {
if (k == '') return v;
return `${v} - ${arr[v]}`;
}, 2);
```

```js
var arr = ('Привет, как твои дела? Привет, нормально, а как твои?').toLowerCase().replace(/[.,\/#!?$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g, "").split(' ');

for (var len = arr.length, i = len; --i >= 0;) {
  if (arr[arr[i]]) {
    arr[arr[i]] += 1;
    arr.splice(i, 1);
  } else {
    arr[arr[i]] = 1;
  }
}
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return arr[b] - arr[a];
});

console.log(arr);
var stringResult = JSON.stringify(arr, function(k, v) {
  if (k == '') return v;
  return `${v} - ${arr[v]}`;
}, 2);
console.log(stringResult);
```

Comment: *для чего используется здесь двойной массив* Ихде? это вот про это: `arr[arr[i]]`? Дык это не двойной массив, а элемент массива `arr`, индекс которого берётся из элемента массива `arr` с индексом `i`.

Comment: @Akina а почему тогда нельзя просто написать arr[i]?

Comment: @СотниЛичностей, _Объясните что делает данный код?_ - считает количество повторений слов.

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, это я знаю. мне нужно узнать то, что я написал ниже

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае используется возможность, позволяющая хранить в массиве не числовые ключи.

Благодаря ей можно подсчитывать количество повторений слов без дополнительных переменных.

`arr[i]` - возвращает конкретное слово
`arr[arr[i]]` - позволяет обратиться к свойству массива с именем соответствующим значению `arr[i]`.

Так если `arr[i] == "Привет"`, то `arr[arr[i]]` -> `arr["Привет"]`.

Внутри цикла:

```
for (var len = arr.length, i = len; --i >= 0;) {
  if (arr[arr[i]]) { // если слово уже встречалось
    arr[arr[i]] += 1; // увеличиваем счетчик
    arr.splice(i, 1); // удаляем элемент массива
  } else { // иначе
    arr[arr[i]] = 1; // устанавливаем счетчик 
  }
}
```

происходит подсчет слов, и удаление повторных вхождений слов.

Далее происходит сортировка массива на основе количества повторений слов

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  // a,b здесь это слова `"Привет"` и т.д.  соответственно `arr[a]` - вернет количество повторений слова.
  return arr[b] - arr[a];
});
```

---

Код с [JSON.stringify](http://docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) нужен только для красивого вывода. За красивый вывод отвечает функция передаваемая в качестве параметра. Если ее не указывать выведется просто массив слов, в данном же случае дополнительно выводится количество повторений каждого слова.

```js
var arr = ('Привет старушка, как дела? Дела у меня, хорошо меня. Привет старушка, как дела? Дела у меня, хорошо меня. Привет старушка, как дела? Дела у меня, хорошо меня.').toLowerCase().replace(/[.,\/#!?$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g, "").split(' ');

for (var len = arr.length, i = len; --i >= 0;) {
  if (arr[arr[i]]) {
    arr[arr[i]] += 1;
    arr.splice(i, 1);
  } else {
    arr[arr[i]] = 1;
  }
}
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return arr[b] - arr[a];
});

console.log(arr);
var stringResult = JSON.stringify(arr, function(k, v) {
  if (k == '') return v;
  return `${v} - ${arr[v]}`;
}, 2);
console.log(stringResult);
```

Comment: понял, спасибо. но вот я сейчас проверил, если вставить в текст, допустим, повторение например: "Привет старушка, как дела? Дела у меня, хорошо меня.Привет старушка, как дела? Дела у меня, хорошо меня.Привет старушка, как дела? Дела у меня, хорошо меня." то некоторые слова перестаю считаться циклом. в тексте 6 слов "меня", а код выдаст только 4 повторения. В чём ошибка кода?

Comment: @СотниЛичностей, в том, как ты делишь строку на слова. Из-за того, что ты пропустил несколько пробелов, при текущем делении ты получил слова `меняпривет` и считаешь их как одно слово, а не два

Comment: да, тоже заметил это. Исправил, добавил нужные пробелы, но ошибка осталась `Привет старушка, как дела? Дела у меня, хорошо меня. Привет старушка, как дела? Дела у меня, хорошо меня. Привет старушка, как дела? Дела у меня, хорошо меня.`

Comment: @СотниЛичностей, у меня не воспроизводится `меня` показывает 6 как и должно быть.

Comment: Можешь скинуть свой код который ты вставляешь? может быть я что-то пропускаю...

Comment: @СотниЛичностей, добавил в ответ сниппет с твоей новой строкой.